# MYSQL select all expired subscribers

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database tables:

```
subscribers: (ID, name, email_address etc)
```

And
    subscriptions: (subsc_id, user_id, subsc_start, subsc_end)

My question is how can I get a result of all expired members? I wrote an SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions
LEFT JOIN subscribers
ON subscriptions.user_id = subscribers.ID 
WHERE DATE(subscription.subsc_end) < DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY subscriptions.user_id
```

The problem is if a subscriber has an active subscription but also has an earlier expired subscription, then that subscriber will be also added to the expired list.

Can anybody help me to write the proper query?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try using a having clause:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions
  LEFT JOIN subscribers 
    ON subscriptions.user_id = subscribers.ID 
GROUP BY subscriptions.user_id
  HAVING MAX(DATE(subscriptions.subsc_end)) < DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to find users whose expiry date is in the past AND their start date is *before* their expiry date - so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions
LEFT JOIN subscribers 
ON subscriptions.user_id = subscribers.ID 
WHERE DATE(subscriptions.subsc_end) < DATE(NOW()) 
AND DATE(subscriptions.subsc_start) < DATE(subscriptions.subsc_end)
GROUP BY subscriptions.user_id
HAVING MAX(DATE(subscriptions.subsc_end)) < DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Unforutnately it gives me back the same result as before.
e.g I have a subscriber who has an active subscription and he also has 3 earlier expired subscription records in the database.

When I list active subscribers then this user is in this list but when I list all expired subscribers then this user is in expired list too.

Comment: Does each user have a single row, or multiple rows? It's difficult to see where the issue lies without understanding how you're handling your users' data!

Comment: One user can have multiple rows in the subscriptions table

Comment: On what occasion would they have a second row?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the subscription is for paper like magazines.

Comment: So for example when a user's subscription expires soon, he has an option to subscribe for the next period. Then he will have two (or more) rows in the subscriptions table

Comment: See edit - added `HAVING MAX` clause so that it only looks for the row with the last `subsc_end` value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you "soft delete" old subscriptions anytime someone renews his? 
add a "renewed" field to your second table, and anytime someone renews his subscription, push your timestamp to the renewed field of his old one so that you can exclude it in your queries?

Comment: For example there is an option to subscribe for the next period so we mustn't delete the older (active) subscription
And also we have to store the individual subscriptions' transactions too so we can check if something is wrong with the transaction

Comment: You wouldn't be deleting them. that's why it's called soft delete. they're still stored in your db, but they're flagged for you to know that there's a newer one

Answer (score 0):

Do this with a php script, so you can display all expired users.

```
$get_exp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions LEFT JOIN subscribers ON subscriptions.user_id = subscribers.ID GROUP BY subscriptions.user_id") or die(mysql_error());;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_exp)){
       $now = time();
       $end_date = strtotime($row['subsc_end']);
       $exp_date = ($end_date - $now);
       $totDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
        if($totDays < 0){
            //display user, he/she expired
        }
     }
```

Comment: please don't use mysql_* extension code. It is completely insecure, deprecated, don't support a lot of features and is already removed in PHP7. Using mysqli cost exactly adding an "i" to mysql ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN of non expired subscriptions to subscribers, and check in the WHERE clause that no non expired subscription is found.

Saves any aggregate functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM subscribers
LEFT JOIN subscriptions
ON subscriptions.user_id = subscribers.ID 
AND DATE(subscription.subsc_end) > DATE(NOW())
WHERE subscriptions.subsc_id IS NULL
```